# Is disabling spell check systemwide still possible in Sierra?

Tags: macos, spellcheck

I wanted to comment my question directly in the thread *[Is it possible to disable spell check systemwide?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151527/is-it-possible-to-disable-spell-check-systemwide)* , but I do not have enough reputation to comment, so I opened a new thread:

I just upgraded from El Capitan to Sierra and wanted to disable spell check as always for years now with this procedure:

```
sudo mv /System/Library/Services/AppleSpell.service/Contents/Resources \
        /System/Library/Services/AppleSpell.service/Contents/Resources.disabled
killall AppleSpell
```

Unfortunately this procedure doesn't work anymore as the *Resources* file does not exist anymore in `System/Library/Services/AppleSpell.service/Contents`

Does anybody know how to get rid of the spell check in Sierra?

Comment: Read the top answer to that question. It provides the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @Mark The top answer and all the answers to this post https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151527/is-it-possible-to-disable-spell-check-systemwide provides solution for the ones using Yosemite/Sierra, it doesn't works anymore for High Sierra, I have tried the mention steps, unfortuanetly it didn't worked. AppleSpell.service process keeps working in the background!

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the feature that automatically corrects misspellings but it still underlines misspelled words. Go to System Preferences, Keyboard and click on the Text tab. There is an option on the right to correct spelling automatically. Make sure this is not checked.

Comment: I tried this option but it still underlines misspelled words and the AppleSpell.service process keeps workking in the background inspite of disabling it from system preferences