# How to disable "Spelling and Grammar" globally, for all apps?

Tags: macos, mojave, settings, spellcheck

I have searched for the similar title, got a few answers which are not applicable to my case:

- [Is disabling spell check systemwide still possible in Sierra?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282080/is-disabling-spell-check-systemwide-still-possible-in-sierra) (redirects to the next link)
- [Is it possible to disable spell check systemwide?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151527/is-it-possible-to-disable-spell-check-systemwide) (does not work post-Sierra)

I have "System settings > Keyboard > Text > Correct spelling automatically" turned off.

Many applications have their own spellchecking flag, which can be changed via "Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Check Spelling while typing".

What I would like to achieve is to disable all checkboxes under "Spelling and Grammar" menu for all applications. I believe it should be possible via something like `defaults write ...`, but I have no idea what to put there.

Comment: To make things easier for everybody, can you please add some details about *why* the existing answers are not applicable in your case?

Comment: @nohillside updated

Comment: I once wrote a script somewhere on here to check & disable the spell-check in TextEdit… because TextEdit saves that pref **per file.** problem is, I can't find the darn thing right now. I'll keep looking… but I just realised I have 2,200 answers on here :\

Comment: Ahh… got it. It took a lot of fumbling, so there are 3 answers involved to get there. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208746/applescript-wont-invoke-shortcut-command